# VLC object onclick handler

Tags: javascript, vlc

I am working with the VLC ActiveX plugin in IE 10, and am trying to register an on click handler to both modify the video playback and show/hide other divs contained in the application. Everything I have tried/found has not been successful. I am attempting to grab the VLC playback object by

```
var CTA = document.getElementById('CTAMain');
CTA.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('CTA Main clicked');
});
```

Typical routes of registering an event listener have been unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your HTML - how you register and display the object?

Comment: <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" id="CTAMain" name="CTAMain"
                    width="1080"
                    height="1544"
                    codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
                <param name="Src" value="/videos/50-off-custom-folio_fs_inactive.mp4"/>
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false"/>
                <param name="Toolbar" value="false"/>
                <param name="AutoLoop" value="True"/>
                <param name="AutoPlay" value="True"/>
            </object>

Comment: You may want to use `attachEvent` for IE10, see https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin for more info

Comment: Adding an event to the object itself seems to not be possible. I am now trying to use the 'windowless' param to allow for a transparent div overlay to handle the event, but the windowless param does not seem to work in IE 10 or 11. :/

Comment: How about simple position DIV over the object?

Comment: That's what I'm attempting right now, and it does not work. The object appears above whatever you attempt to overlay it with, regardless of z-index. The windowless param is supposed to enable placing a div over the object, but it isn't working.

Comment: I was able to successfully position an IFRAME over VLC and attach `onclick` to it. Probably this is the way to go - if you could make the IFRAME transparent (I couldnt)